# PayPal WooCommerce Connect multiple websites with one PayPal account

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

I have two brands, each with their own website. Website A is already using PayPal, now I want to connect Website B, but I can only specify one return URL in PayPal.

Is it possible to connect multiple WooCommerce stores to one PayPal Account? If so, how does it work? Does WooCommerce sends its own overwrite for the return url?

Comment: No u cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does WooCommerce sends its own overwrite for the return url?

The PayPal payment method you have configured in woocommerce may or may not use a return URL. If it does, it will specify it when it sets up the transaction. The setting in your PayPal account is irrelevant.

Comment: We are using the standard PayPal integration that comes bundled with WooCommerce (no PayPal Express). So there is only one payment method.

Comment: The "standard" PayPal integration that you say comes bundled with WooCommerce may or may not use a return URL. If it does, it will specify it when it sets up the transaction. The setting in your PayPal account is irrelevant.